# How to calculate the following integral? $\int_{a}^{b}\frac{e^{u}}{u^{c}}du$ with a non integer strictly positive real?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to calculate the following integral?

$$\int_{a}^{b}\frac{e^{u}}{u^{c}}du$$

with a, b  and c real positive numbers ? In particular, c may not be an integer.

Comment: Even for integer values of $c$, the integral has not a *nice* closed form: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ex%2Fx

Comment: So you can only compute it numerically.

Comment: If i use the Wolfram Math IA, the antiderivative equals $$(-x)^c \Gamma(1 - c, -x)/x^y$$

Comment: Beware however that If c must be inferior to one if i want the incomplete gamma function to have any meaning... In my question, i expect c to be any real strict positive number.

Comment: @Miguel i disagree: when c is a positive integer, you may rely on the Exponential Integral functions...

Comment: Well, it's a question of how you define *closed form*. I wouldn't call an exponential integral function a closed form.

Comment: @GerryMyerson As i can get the exponential integral computed with a very good precision, i can consider it to be a "closed form"

Comment: The exponential integral is defined to be $-\int_{-x}^{\infty}t^{-1}e^{-t}\,dt$. So if you consider it to be a closed form, then you're saying a closed form for $-\int_{-x}^{\infty}t^{-1}e^{-t}\,dt$ is $-\int_{-x}^{\infty}t^{-1}e^{-t}\,dt$. In any event, if you have a good way to compute the exponential integral, then doesn't it also give you a good way to compute $\int_a^bu^{-c}e^u\,du$?

Comment: Any thoughts, Ben?

Comment: I guess not. Bye-bye, Ben.

Comment: if i follow you, even sin, cos, exp and ln are not closed form as there values are only approximations computed by series approximations and other numeric tricks... The fact is that if can achieve single or double machine precision calculus for these functions, i may consider these functions to be closed forms...

Comment: Fine, but to repeat myself, doesn't your method for computing $\int_x^{\infty}t^{-1}e^{-t}\,dt$ extend to computing $\int_a^bu^{-c}e^u\,du$? Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.

Comment: Gone away again, Ben?